# How to build a model for multistep prediction when input sequence length and target sequence length are not equal?

Tags: time-series, tensorflow

I want to input a sequence of length 60 (time steps) and I would like to use it for predicting a sequence of length 20.

So, I built the following model:

```
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, LSTM, Reshape

print("train_input_seqs.shape:", train_input_seqs.shape)
print("train_target_seqs.shape:", train_target_seqs.shape)

n_lstm_units = 50
n_features = train_input_seqs.shape[-1] # = 19
input_length = train_input_seqs.shape[1] # = 60
output_length = train_target_seqs.shape[1] # = 20

input_layer = Input(shape=(input_length, n_features))
lstm = LSTM(units=n_lstm_units, return_sequences=True)(input_layer)
dense = Dense(units=1)(lstm) 
output_layer = Reshape([output_length, 1])(dense)

plain_vanilla_lstm_model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
plain_vanilla_lstm_model.summary()
```

When I run this code I get the following error message:

```
train_input_seqs.shape: (48983, 60, 19)
train_target_seqs.shape: (48983, 20, 1)
...
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged, input_shape = [60, 1], output_shape = [20, 1]
```

While I do understand why this is happening, I was wondering how I should modify my model in order to account for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the solution is actually pretty simple:

I just had to modify the `dense = Dense(units=1)(lstm)` part and replace it with `dense = Dense(units=output_length)(lstm)` to make this work.

Now the length of the input sequence is 60 timesteps with a dimensionality of 19 and the output sequence will be of 20 timesteps with a dimensionality of 1.